# How can I return an object with the longest string in a list of dictionaries? (python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

any idea how I can return the object with the longest name in the following example?

```
def instructorWithLongestName(instructors):

    instructors = [ 
      {'name': "Samuel", 'course': "iOS"},
      {'name': "Jeremiah", 'course': "Data"},
      {'name': "Ophilia", 'course': "Web"},
      {'name': "Donald", 'course': "Web"}
      {'name': "Matthew", 'course': "Data"},
      {'name': "David", 'course': "iOS"},
      {'name': "Domascus", 'course': "Web"}
    ]
    
    max_len = -1
    for name in instructors:
        if len(name) > max_len:
            max_len = len(name)
            res = name


print(instructorWithLongestName([
  {name: "Samuel", course: "iOS"},
  {name: "Jeremiah", course: "Data"},
  {name: "Ophilia", course: "Web"},
  {name: "Donald", course: "Web"}
]))
print(instructorWithLongestName([
  {name: "Matthew", course: "Data"},
  {name: "David", course: "iOS"},
  {name: "Domascus", course: "Web"}
]))
```

This should be the expected output:

```
    {name: "Jeremiah", course: "Data"}
    {name: "Domascus", course: "Web"}
```

I'm getting a SyntaxError in my instructors List, but was hoping this would do the trick. Clearly it's not. Any help would be appreciated - thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's something real in your code, or just an artifact of copying it here, but you're overriding the `instructors` argument passed in to your function with a constant dictionary. You probably don't want to do that!

Comment: `name` and `course` should be in quotes: wrong: `{name: "Samuel", course: "iOS"}`, right: `{'name': "Samuel", 'course': "iOS"},`

Comment: Alternatively `dict` converts its keyword arguments to string keys: `dict(name='Samuel', course='iOS')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def instructorWithLongestname(instructors):
    return max(instructors, key=lambda d:len(d['name']))

print(instructorWithLongestname([
  {'name': "Samuel", 'course': "iOS"},
  {'name': "Jeremiah", 'course': "Data"},
  {'name': "Ophilia", 'course': "Web"},
  {'name': "Donald", 'course': "Web"}
]))
print(instructorWithLongestname([
  {'name': "Matthew", 'course': "Data"},
  {'name': "David", 'course': "iOS"},
  {'name': "Domascus", 'course': "Web"}
]))
```

prints

```
{'name': 'Jeremiah', 'course': 'Data'}
{'name': 'Domascus', 'course': 'Web'}
```

Comment: What was the `SyntaxError` with the example?

Answer (score 0):

```
instructors = [ 
      {'name': "Samuel", 'course': "iOS"},
      {'name': "Jeremiah", 'course': "Data"},
      {'name': "Ophilia", 'course': "Web"},
      {'name': "Donald", 'course': "Web"},
      {'name': "Matthew", 'course': "Data"},
      {'name': "David", 'course': "iOS"},
      {'name': "Domascus", 'course': "Web"}
    ]
```

if you are given variable "instructors" and you are going to get a dict with longest name

```
def f(items):
    return max(items, key=lambda item: len(item.get('name')))
```